# How to send an sms to a phone number via internet?

Tags: sms, sms-gateway, sms-verification

I would like to send an SMS verification code from a web page to a phone number exactly like what *Facebook* or *Google* are doing when someone wants to register on their websites.

So, is there any idea or a free API services that could send SMS over the internet ?

Comment: *free services* - is there a sim that you don't need to top-up?

Comment: google and facebook has there own SMS gateway I believed or they are paying this service on a certain provider. Create your own, but the thing *free* is not really achievable. But you could try Ozeki, http://www.ozekisms.com/ , I've tried couple times, but I've created my app in c#.net since I only got an API support for c#, so I'm sure if they have support to web.

Comment: unlikely they have there own gateway, rather just use a third party provider.

Comment: @KDOT actually there is some websites where you can send a free sms but they make a limit and a captcha every time you want send a sms . that's why I think it could be free.

Answer (score 2):

In my experience there are no reliable free providers of web to SMS gateways. Some mobile phone providers do provide a limited service where you can send an email for SMS delivery to their network using their gateway, but this is usually also limited and restricted. And probably prohibited if you are doing anything vaguely commercial with it.

There are plenty of paid services available which are reasonably priced if you plan to do anything important with the SMSs. These providers typically provide you with a web service API to send messages, but many also provide an email to SMS gateway. Google is your friend as far as finding a specific provider is concerned.

Comment: agreed, avoid all 'free' or carrier specific ones.

Comment: @WilliamD Thanks for your response
But I have some doubts about SMS gateway
I found this list of sevice providers and their SMS-Gateways
[SMS-Carriers](https://davidwalsh.name/demo/SMS-Carriers.pdf)

My question is :

if we know the service provider of the reciepent
can we send him a msg using the smsGateway on the list above?

Comment: You could certainly experiment with the gateways listed in the document, but don't count on all of them still being up or being reliable. Providers have various policies surrounding their services and some might need you to register your email address before being allowed to send, for example. If you're not getting the results you're expecting from your email, it would be best to contact the carrier directly and have them provide specific instructions on how to use the services they offer.

Comment: Happy I could help

Answer (score 0):

you need to use Google api cloud messaging https://developers.google.com/cloud-messaging/